# How to rewrite tex file using lua

Tags: luatex

I try to solve the problem with `$` and `$$` in formulas, to perform automatic tagging of these formulas, including adding in the structure tree. Variant with `\grabinline` or `\grabdisplay` does not work for me because I get an error when tryingto use `equation`, for example. Recently I read that I can work with my own files via `lualatex`. First I tried to simply replace `$$` and `$` if there is no `\` character before, but not only does it not work, but my file is corrupted when I try to rewrite it, I mean, it adds new strange lines.

Please help me, how can I fix this problem, I mean the problem with the corruption of thefile, and please explain to me why it happens?

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{require("test.lua")}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
test
$$a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$
\end{document}
```

`test.lua`

```lua
f=io.open(tex.jobname..".tex","r+")
lines=f:lines()
for line in lines do
line=line:gsub("([^\\]?)$$(.+-)$$","%1\\[%2\\]")
line=line:gsub("([^\\]?)$(.+-)$","%1\\(%2\\)")
texio.write_nl("line of file "..line)
f:write(line)
end
f:close()
```

Comment: Why are you opening the input file a second time but in Lua?  Why are writing the substituted content to the log instead of a new file?

Comment: Please provide more background as to what you're trying to achieve. Separately, would you be ok with a LuaLaTeX-based solution that performs the substitution of the `$$` and `$` symbols "on the fly", i.e., without writing its modified input stream back to file?

Comment: Maybe a solution outside of LaTeX would be easier, i.e., preprocess the file with any programming language or command line tool that you prefer and run LaTeX afterwards?

Comment: @Henri Menke Because i want to do modification of my file,and compile after that modifiered file,but help me please,how i can rewrite existing file in lua? Why in lualatex problem with this? I even tryed open existing file in read mode,get lines,close it and open it in w mode,but in this case i can't works with line variable. Explain me please,why my file corrupted and how rewrite existing file. I not ask you now help me with substitutions,i only help to you help me with rewriting an existing file. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: @Mico i am not understood your idea,how i can do replacing $ and $$ without modifying of file? And it very interesting for me,what the secret of lualatex,that it corrupted the file and write strange lines. Why my code with rewriting of file not works. Can someone please explain to me this secret of lualatex. I dont want use special tools for substitution,because i want to implement this solution in my package and if i will do it in lualatex,i can do my solution more crossplatform.I hope that you will explain to me your idea solution of my problem.

Comment: @Mico But i also want to understood behaviour of lualatex when i rewrite my own file. If nobody dontt know,why this happends,give me please email of lualatex team,,to i can ask at them,why this happends. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not TeX related, it is a general problem with reading and writing the same file. So what is going on?

The output you probably get is

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}t.lua")}
t.lua")}le{empty}
le{empty}cument}
cument}a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$
a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$
```

This happens because after opening your original file, you are at the first byte of the first line. Then using `lines`, you read the first line: `\documentclass{article}`. After that, your position in the line is the beginning of the second line. Here you issue `f:write`, so the first, unmodified, line is written to the current position in the file, which is the second line. It overwrites existing content.

So now, the file contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}t.lua")}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
test
$$a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$
\end{document}
```

and your current position is at the end of the second `\documentclass{article}`.
Now your next `lines` iteration reads the rest of the line, so you get `t.lua")}`.
Then you are at the start of the third line and you overwrite it with the just read text, so you get

```
documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}t.lua")}
t.lua")}le{empty}
\begin{document}
test
$$a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$
\end{document}
```

This repeats for every line, until you get the file you observed.

Which lesson can you learn here:
Do not overwrite a file while you are still reading from it!

In contrast some other programming languages contain functions, like Python with `readlines`, which on the first glance look similar to Lua's `io.lines`. But e.g. Python's `readlines` directly reads all lines into an array, while Lua only reads one line at a time in every iteration of the loop. So no quite so obvious problems appear with similar code there because reading and writing is clearly separated: Reading only during `readline`, writing afterwards.

Anyway rewriting your TeX source file during the TeX run is very dangerous and also not compatible (Windows is sensible when it comes to editing open files).

It is much safer and easier to use `process_input_buffer` if you only want to change one line at a time. You can use `status.input_ptr` to only affect lines from specific files: (I fixed the pattern in the process)

```
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", function(line)
  if status.input_ptr ~= 1 then return end -- Only change lines of the main file
  texio.write_nl("line of file "..line)
  print(line:match("([^\\]?)$$(.-)$%$"))
  return line:gsub("([^\\]?)$$(.-)$%$","%1\\[%2\\]")
             :gsub("([^\\]?)$(.-)%$","%1\\(%2\\)")
end, "my_math_rewrite")
```

Even if this is much less dangerous, I would still recommend looking for ways to archive your goals without rewriting input lines.

Comment: %c3%bcger
Marcel Krüger yes,my file have similar structure,and i want to understood,it issue of lua,or it normal works of lua,because in python i can without any problem rewrite the same file. and for lua,as i understood,i must add all lines of file in table,than open it in write mode and after that i can write again my table in file. but it seems,when i get lines of file,i loose the last character of each line,so i dont know,if line finish by \n or \r character. May be it exists some ways to solve this problems?

Comment: I desided to use for substitutions modifying of file,because at first i can get emmidiately all lines of file and at second in process_input_buffer i get not only lines of documents,but also line of all packages,which i use in document and also some latex lines.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Are you using `readlines` in your Python code?

Comment: Yes,status.input_ptr works for me,but i desided to use features of regular expressions of lua in this callback. Sorry for offtopic,but it not understandable for me,why my regular expression ([^\\]?)%$ not works,ie if before $ is \ character,it works such as it haven't \ character before $,but it mustn't return to me any result.Yes,i know,that in lua very bad features of regular expressions,but as i read,i also can use in lua [^set]? construction,which means,that it can be any character before the next part of regular expression,except characters,which we can see between [ and ] and after ^

Comment: ^ character or this part of regular expression must start emmidiately. So,why my regular expression not works correct,and how to change it,that it works correct. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Comments are not the right place to ask new questions and I do not understand what you are asking. Please create a new question here (if it is TeX specific) or on StackOverflow (if it is a general Lua question)

Comment: Ok,i try write regular expression,which find,for example,$ or $$,if before it no character,or if before any character,except \. Why,for example,for $ my regular expression ie ([^\\]?)%$ not works correct? Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy - Be careful when using the term "regular expression" in a Lua context: Lua does *not* -- at least not natively -- support regular expressions and regexp syntax. What Lua performs in its string functions, such as `find`, `match`, `gmatch`, `sub`, and `gsub`, is   "pattern matching". For more on the topic of the difference between regexp language and pattern matching see, e.g., the posting [Lua pattern matching vs. regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693334/1014365).

Answer (score 5):

(a little bit late to the party, but hopefully still useful)

Here's a solution which doesn't create a new text file. Instead, it works "on the fly", essentially like a pre-processor, and replaces matching pairs of `$$` and `$`, respectively, with their LaTeX-preferred expressions: This happens *before* TeX starts its usual work of expanding macros, etc.

Creating a new output text file, to write out the on-the-fly-modified contents of the input put, is left as a separate exercise.

To take this from the proof-of-concept stage to something that might be sufficiently robust for real-world work, one would certainly also have to add code to test whether the material being examined by the preprocessor happens to in verbatim mode or is contained in a URL string. In these and similar cases, no substitutions should be performed, right?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

%% Create external file to store Lua code:
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.lua}
```

```lua
function substitute_dollar_symbols ( line )
    line = line:gsub ( "([^\\]?)$$(.+-)$$" , "%1\\[%2\\]" )
    line = line:gsub ( "([^\\]?)$(.+-)$"   , "%1\\(%2\\)" )
    return line
end
```

```tex
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%% Load Lua code from external file:
\directlua{require("test.lua")}

%% Create two LaTeX utility macros to (a) assign Lua 
%% function to the "process_input_buffer" callback 
%% and (b) remove the function from that callback:
\newcommand\SubstituteDollarSymbolsOn{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", 
    substitute_dollar_symbols , 
    "substitute_dollar_symbols" )}}
\newcommand\SubstituteDollarSymbolsOff{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
    "process_input_buffer",
    "substitute_dollar_symbols" )}}

%% Activate the Lua function at start of document:
\AtBeginDocument{\SubstituteDollarSymbolsOn}

\begin{document}
test
$$a+b=a^b$$ $a-b=a/b$ % $$ $
abc $$uvw$$
\end{document}
```